# Check free space in Linux

Tags: java, diskspace

I'm using this code to check Free space in Linux:

```
public final class EnvironmentCheck
{
    public EnvironmentCheck()
    {
        // If the HDD Free Space is less than 200 Megabytes write message HDD is too low
        if (200 > checkHDDFreeSpace())
        {
            System.out.println("*** WARNING Hard Drive free space " + checkHDDFreeSpace() + " Megabytes " + "is too low! ***");
        }

        // If the RAM Free Space is less than 200 Megabytes write message HDD is too low
        if (200 > checkRAMFreeSpace())
        {
            System.out.println("*** WARNING RAM free space " + checkRAMFreeSpace() + " Megabytes " + "is too low! ***");
        }
    }

    public long checkHDDFreeSpace()
    {
        long availableSpace = 0;

        FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
        for (FileStore store : fs.getFileStores())
        {
            try
            {
                availableSpace = store.getUsableSpace() / 1024;
                //System.out.println(availableSpace);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
        }
        return availableSpace;
    }

    public long checkRAMFreeSpace()
    {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    }
}
```

For some reason I get always message when I run the code on Linux.

```
*** WARNING Hard Drive free space <some value> Megabytes is too low! **
```

Can you help me to fix my mistake.

I don't see this message on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things that are not working in your code:

1) `FileStore.getUsableSpace()` returns a number of *bytes*. If you want MBs, you need to divide by 1024*1024 instead of just 1024:

```
availableSpace = store.getUsableSpace() / (1024*1024);
```

2) `Runtime.freeMemory()` returns the number of unused bytes for the *current size of the heap*. The heap grows or shrinks dynamically, and may not have reached its *maximum size*. If what you want is the number of bytes that can be allocated, you need the following:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
return rt.maxMemory() - (rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory());
```

3) same as for 1), if you want MBs, you need to divide by 1024*1024:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long freeMem = rt.maxMemory() - (rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory());
return freeMem / (1024 * 1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo? Your if conditions are identical. Also, in windows it could be that the condition evaluates to "200 > 1" or some number equal or less than 200. This would result in you never seeing the message in windows. Just a guess but you will have to debug. Start by changing the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logic:

```
    for (FileStore store : fs.getFileStores())
            availableSpace = store.getUsableSpace() / 1024;
    }
    return availableSpace;
```

You get the available space on every iteration, but you OVERWRITE the space from the previous iteration. So you're getting the space of the LAST filesystem you're iterating, which may very well have less than 200meg of space.

Putting in some debug output, e.g. printing out `availableSpace` on ever iteration, would definitely help figure this out.